# Hibernate objects not getting mapped when creating a JAX-WS web service

Tags: java, web-services, hibernate, wsdl

I am generating a web service in Java with Eclipse IDE that has a class with methods that query the database through Hibernate mapped DAOs. If I create the web service without using all the Hibernate types (as a parameter passed to methods or a return type) it succeed, If I try to use all my Hibernate beans in order to have them mapped it fails. anyone faced this problem before?

The problem is I dont have all the Hibernate objects mapped in the web service. of course not having some they are underfined when I need to use them from by a client that uses the service.

Anyone faced this problem?

Thanks, I appreciate any help...

Comment: Could you clarify the second and third sentences, or add a code snippet to illustrate what you mean?

Comment: How does it fail?  Does it throw an exception?  If so could you provide the stack trace?  Does it map the wrong class?  Are you missing properties?  Do you have any inheritance going on?

Comment: thank you for your intrest to help,

Comment: Thanks you, It gives back a non very comprehansable problem, I'll will post code as answer in a bit,

This is the error if sounds familiar to you

'An internal error occurred during: "Generating JAX-WS Web Services".
Unable to create JAXBContext'


This error occurs in the class I am creating the WS for when I mention/use 2 of my 6 Hibernate beans. If I don't mention/use them then I don't get the error but they don't get mapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by adding `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter( TimestampAdapter.class)` BUT by creating the TimestampAdapter class having it returning a `java.util.Date` instead of `java.sql.Date`

Answer (score 0):

In my example the first method 'mapVM' of the class below returns a set of 'VmStatistics' causes the faliure as follows:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Generating JAX-WS Web Services".
Unable to create JAXBContext
```

While if I take the method off the Hibernate object 'VmStatistics' doesn't get mapped when the ws is created. Same it happens with other objects, so I am missing beans in the ws.

The hibernate logic is in a jar file and contains 6 beans.

This is my class to generate WS for (contains 5 methods)

```
   public class DBHelper {

    public DBHelper(){}

          public static Set<VmStatistics> mapVM(Vm vm){

        Set< VmStatistics> s = vm.getVmStatisticses();
        return s;
    }



    /**
     * Loads all companies
     * 
     * @return A list of company objects
     */
    public static ArrayList<Company> getCompanyList(){
        ArrayList<Company> lCompanies = new ArrayList<Company>();

                    ...

                    return lCompanies;
    }

    /**
     * Loads all the available countries
     * 
     * @return
     * Returns a list of string objects
     */
    public static ArrayList<String> getCountryList(){
        ArrayList<String> lCountires = new ArrayList<String>();

        ...     

                    return lCountires;
    }

    /**
     * Loads the companies of the given country name
     * 
     * @param pCountry a given country name
     * 
     * @return A list of company objects
     */
    public static ArrayList<Company> getCompanyListByCountry(String pCountry){
        ArrayList<Company> lCompanies = new ArrayList<Company>();

                    ...
                    return lCompanies;
    }

    /**
     * Loads the latest reading performed in the datacenter
     * 
     * @param pCountry
     * A given country name
     * 
     * @param pCompany
     * A given company object
     * 
     * @return The list of server objects which contains the associated VMs and the relative statistics
     */
    public static Collection<Server> getCurrentReading(String pCountry, Company pCompany){
                 ...
                return lServer;
    }

}
```

Now I tried to add the beans manually in the schema file and wsdl of the ws and it accepts it but in deploy on tomcat phase it gives the same error, but since it is a log error and not an eclipse i think it is more clear to understand:

I tried to generated manually by modifying the sdl and schema files and adding the types that dont get mapped...and in deploy on tomcat face it gives the same error...maybe this will be more clear sicne it is a log error:

```
SEVERE: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Unable to create JAXBContext
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Unable to create JAXBContext
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.createJAXBContext(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:158)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.postProcess(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:87)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:262)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createSEIModel(EndpointFactory.java:322)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:188)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:467)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parseAdapters(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:253)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parse(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:147)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.contextInitialized(WSServletContextListener.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3843)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4342)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:830)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1149)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:578)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
java.sql.Timestamp does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at java.sql.Timestamp
        at public java.sql.Timestamp org.qcri.power.db.AbstractServerStatistics.getTimestamp()
        at org.qcri.power.db.AbstractServerStatistics
        at org.qcri.power.db.ServerStatistics
        at private java.util.Set org.qcri.power.ws.jaxws.MapServerResponse._return
        at org.qcri.power.ws.jaxws.MapServerResponse

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.createJAXBContext(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:148)
    ... 32 more
```

Thank you,

Comment: I did some progress and now the problem is a timestamp error. There is two work arounds on forums:

1. Make the field as XmlJavaTypeAdapter by annotation: with the annotation id doesnt work and gives the same error.

2. Make the field private for no exposure: by making it private it works and generates correctly the ws but once the object is used on the client side the field is always null.

Any idea pls?

Comment: In the referenced class by annotation, I changed java.sql.Date to java.util.Date. This fixed it.